# How can I display the index[0] value from an item list?

Tags: list, indexing, freemarker

I have an item list with a department field. While retrieving the department field from the item list, I only want to display the first department value (index[0]).

I tried using the ?first but it doesn't work right.

What syntax should be used for this?

Comment: This is through Freemarker. How to get the value of index 0

Comment: Exactly what problem you run into with `?first`? It used to work. Also `[0]`.

Comment: Hi @ddekany, I've been trying to use the ?first to retrieve the first value of my list that is indexed. But seems that this is not allowed (?)

Comment: `?first` should work with listable values. What's the error message?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to get index 0 by [Retrieving data from a sequence](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_var_sequence)

```
 department[0]
```

> (remember that the number of the first item is 0, not 1): animals[0].name

Comment: Hi @user7294900, that seems like a plan. I will try it. Although, I also found a work-around which is by using <#if index==0> inside my <#list>.. and it retrieves the index 0 value.